# Class initialization on C# Unit Test fails

Tags: c#, unit-testing

New to unit testing. I need to have an app called SolidWorks start up and load a file. My initialization will not run. I get the error:

> Class Initialization method UnitTestProject1.SolidWorksPartTests.MyClassInitialize threw exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks, Version=27.1.0.72, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c4797c3e4eeac03' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

I know for certain that the reference in there. I think this has something to do with static references. My code looks like this:

```
    private TestContext testContextInstance;
    private static IModelDoc2 model;
    private static SolidWorksPart solidWorksPart;
    private static ISldWorks app;

    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext) 
    {
        string testFolderLocation = @"C:\Users\erics\source\repos\XXXXXXXXXXXX\UnitTestProject1\TestFileFolder\";
        var progId = "SldWorks.Application";
        var progType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progId);
        app = System.Activator.CreateInstance(progType) as ISldWorks;
        app.Visible = false;

        string testFilePath = testFolderLocation + "FF99999 Circle.SLDPRT";
        int errors = 0;
        object importData = new object();
        app.LoadFile4(testFilePath, "", importData, ref errors);
        model = (IModelDoc2)app.ActiveDoc;
        solidWorksPart = new SolidWorksPart(model);

    }
```

What is wrong with my class initialization?

**EDIT**
Neither the constructor or the Class initializer runs. The tests I created previously do run though.

Comment: Is the solidworks interop assembly referenced in your project?

Comment: For now, put the whole thing in a try/catch and step through it in the debugger. You can see which line throws the exception. Put a breakpoint inside the catch block so you don't accidentally miss it. Then examine the exception.

Comment: @mratari - yes, it is referenced.

Comment: Tried to load the assembly with depends? Sometimes dependent dlls cannot be loaded. Checked Path?

Comment: @mratari - I have checked path. I have exactly duplicated the references of the project I am testing. When you say "tried to load the assembly with depends" what does that mean? The project I am testing runs.

Comment: @madreflection - The test never gets to start. I've placed breakpoints at both the constructor and the MyClassInitialize function. Execution does not make it to either one. The error I am getting is about a reference that exists at the correct path. I have tried to remove the reference and readding it.

Comment: did you check your App.config? maybe you have binding redirect to another version of SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks. did you remove bin/obj folders of solution?

Comment: Depends.exe or DependencyWalker is a free tool, which shows all dependent loading dlls of a root assembly. Once with a similar problem, it helped me, to extend the path environment variable with the loading paths You can set it in the code. upfront. Brute, but worked for me. By the way, appconfig didn't help that time

Comment: @pwrigshihanomoronimo - I do not have a app.config file that I can see. I did remove the bin/obj folder to no avail.

Comment: I commented out all the lines and started there. IT runs with all lines commented out. I then started uncommenting lines a few at a time. It seems to run until I have an exception of some kind. Once I have an exception the referenced file seems to not load again. I have checked to make sure Solidworks is not running in the background (like it was left hanging). It is not. It just seems to refuse to load again once it is loaded once. IT get it to "reset" I have to comment all the lines and go through the process again.

Comment: @mrAtari - Dependency Walker tells me that there are a whole bunch of missing dependencies. They all seem to be system type files like EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL or IESHIMS.DLL. The puzzle to me is that SolidWorks runs when I run it stand alone. The Solidworks.Interop.sldworks.dll reference runs as well when I test with all the logic commented out. The Solidworks.Interop.sldworks.dll also runs in other non testing projects.

Comment: I just added a new unit test and went step by step. It fails when I add a reference to the assembly I need to test. When I sttempt to "Build All" I get a warning warning MSB3061: Unable to delete file "C:\Users\erics\source\repos\XXXX.XXXX.ToolingAddIn\XXXX.XXXX.ToolingAddIn\bin\Debug\XXXX.XXXX.ToolingAddIn.dll". Access to the path '[shortened].dll' is denied. I can delete these folders manually and the "Rebuild All". The rebuild works the first time. After that it seems the build cannot delete the Debug and Release folders. Visual Studio is running as Admin.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the problem. I had a setting on my project that I was testing. IT was found on "Properties->Debug->StartAction". I had this set to Start External Program to start Solidworks on debug. I changed this to "Start Project". IT **seems** to have fixed the issue.